# Can I use POSIX signals in my Perl program to create event-driven programming?

Tags: perl, ipc, posix, signals, unix

Is there any POSIX signals that I could utilize in my Perl program to create event-driven programming? Currently, I have multi-process program that is able to cross communicate but my parent thread is only able to listen to listen at one child at a time.

```
foreach (@proc) {
  sysread(${$_}{'read'}, my $line, 100); #problem here
  chomp($line);
  print "Parent hears: $line\n";
}
```

The problem is that the parent sits in a continual wait state until it receives it a signal from the first child before it can continue on. I am relying on 'pipe' for my intercommunication.

My current solution is very similar to: [How can I use `pipe` to facilitate interprocess communication in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558098/how-can-i-use-pipe-to-facilitate-interprocess-communication-in-perl)

If possible I would like to rely on a $SIG{...} event or any non-CPAN solution.

**Update:**

As Jonathan Leffler mentioned, kill can be used to send a signal:

[kill  USR1  => $$;                      # send myself a SIGUSR1](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch16_15.htm)

My solution will be to send a USR1 signal to my child process. This event tells the parent to listen to the particular child.

*child:*

```
kill USR1 => $parentPID if($customEvent);
syswrite($parentPipe, $msg, $buffer);
#select $parentPipe; print $parentPipe $msg;
```

*parent:*

```
$SIG{USR1} = {
   #get child pid?
   sysread($array[$pid]{'childPipe'}, $msg, $buffer);   
};
```

1. But how do I get my the source/child pid that signaled the parent?
   *Have the child Identify itself in its message.*
2. What happens if two children signal USR1 at the same time?

**Update 2: Solution**

I went with a select that utilized a vector approach for non-blocking IO.
For those that come across this thread check out: [Perl Cookbook: 7.22. Reading from Many Filehandles Without Blocking](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/perl-cookbook-2nd/0596003137/ch07.html#perlckbk2-CHP-7-SECT-22) as it covers both the vector way and the IO::Select module. I understand the IO::Select module would have been more elegant, but I was more interested in learning new mechanics of Perl. Thank you everyone for your help.

**Exert:**

```
$rin = '';
# repeat next line for all filehandles to poll
vec($rin, fileno(FH1), 1) = 1;
vec($rin, fileno(FH2), 1) = 1;
vec($rin, fileno(FH3), 1) = 1;

$nfound = select($rout=$rin, undef, undef, 0);
if ($nfound) {
  # input waiting on one or more of those 3 filehandles
  if (vec($rout,fileno(FH1),1)) { 
      # do something with FH1
  }
  if (vec($rout,fileno(FH2),1)) {
      # do something with FH2
  }
  if (vec($rout,fileno(FH3),1)) {
      # do something with FH3
  }
}
```

Comment: You know, you can just write the stuff to the pipe... there is no need to send a signal for this stuff.  In the parent, use "select" before read.

Comment: Do you mean `process` or `thread`?  The difference is significant.

Comment: The problem I run into with "select" and the <> operator is that it waits for the current selected child to respond and ignores all the other child processes until it gets a response.

Comment: Well yeah, don't use <>.  Use sysread with the nonblock flag.  Or don't do any of this, and use a proper framework.

Comment: @Shiftbit not that select, the other select.

Comment: I understand now, 'select RBITS,WBITS,EBITS,TIMEOUT' not 'select FILEHANDLE'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [select](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to monitor communications channels (note: if you are on Win32 select can only be used on a socket).

So you can use code like this:

```
use IO::Select;
use IO::Handle;

...

$_->blocking(0) for @handles;

while( 1 ) {
    my $s = IO::Select->new( @handles );

    for my $h ( $s->can_read( 1 ) ) {

        my $data = read_handle($h);
        process_handle_data( $data );
    }

}

sub read_handle {
    my $h = shift;

    my $got = '';

    1 while read( $h, $got, 1024, length $got );

    return $got;
}
```

Take a look at the UDP example in perlipc.  It uses the select built-in.  I prefer the core `IO::Select` module to the `select` built-in, it's much easier to read.

**Update:** You really should consider using an event framework like POE, Event or Coro.  There's a pretty good list of options in [this perlmonks thread](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=828725).  Don't fear CPAN.

Comment: I will take a look. I would definitely consider a CPAN packaged solution professionally. I am new to Perl and Unix Signals so I am trying to wrap my head around the inner workings.

Comment: ok, but signals have nothing to do with this problem.  pipes already have a mechanism for signaling that they are readable.  it's called select.  (or epoll, or kqueue, or ...)

Comment: @Shiftbit, signals are totally unnecessary.  `select` will allow you to monitor multiple handles for available data.  The blocking issues you have are related to `<>` looking for a line of test, and not having your handles in non-blocking mode.  My example shows how to use `read` and make your handles non-blocking.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do event-driven programming, take a look at one of the CPAN event modules, such as  [POE](https://metacpan.org/pod/POE), [Coro](https://metacpan.org/pod/Coro), or [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent) before you invent your own thing.

*Update for 2020*

I'm doing this with [Mojo::EventEmitter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious), which I cover very briefly in my book [Mojo Web Clients](https://leanpub.com/mojo_web_clients).

Answer (score 2):

To answer the direct question, SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 are intended for 'user-defined' purposes - so you could use them.

You might be better off looking at a pre-existing system, though.